# sending short messages using open smpp 3.4

Tags: java, smpp, opensmpp

I have build an application to sending short messages using smpp 3.4 and that work well, but in some phones i got this message:

> Can not display this message

this is my function source code :

```
public String sendMsg(JsonObject paramsIN) {
    String smsMessage = paramsIN.getString("body");
    String smsDestination = paramsIN.getString("to");
    String smsSource = paramsIN.getString("from");
    String smscNAME = paramsIN.getString("smsc");

    SubmitSM request = new SubmitSM();
    SubmitSMResp response;
    Session session;
    try {
        request.setSourceAddr(smsSource);
        request.setDestAddr(smsDestination);
        request.setShortMessage(smsMessage, "UTF-8");
        request.setRegisteredDelivery((byte) 3);
        request.setDataCoding((byte) 4); // 4
        request.assignSequenceNumber(true);
        response = ((Session) sd.get(smscNAME)).submit(request);
        logger.info("Submit response " + response.debugString());
        String messageId = response.getMessageId();       

        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(messageId, 16);  

        return bigInt+"";
    } catch (WrongLengthOfStringException e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return null;
    } catch (PDUException e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return null;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return null;
    } catch (WrongSessionStateException e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

please someone can help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set data coding to 0 (network default) and encode the body with whatever charset your provider supports. Use the GSM default charset if you have to guess ([jcharset](http://www.freeutils.net/source/jcharset/) includes an encoder). If you really need an extended charset use UTF-16BE and set data coding to 8.

Comment: thanks that's works (y). i add this in my code  

`request.setShortMessage(smsMessage, Data.ENC_UTF16_BE);
request.setDataCoding((byte)0x08);`

Comment: Hi teppic thanks for your solution, but i have an other problem that in some other smart phone like "samsung galaxy g1 ace" i have this message "Content not supported"